# How can i save a png in a rectangle?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, png, rectangles

I build a Snake game in Winforms and i need some png's for food.
How can i save a png in a rectangle? 
Here is some code:

```
class Food
{
    #region Variables
    private int x, y, widht = 20, hight = 20;
    private SolidBrush brush;
    public Rectangle foodrectangle;

    int fieldsize_X = 47;// spawnrange
    int fieldsize_Y = 38;// spawnrange
    int squaresize = 20;

    #endregion
```

The "worth" variable is a random number, so i can have random colours.

```
    #region Normal Food

    public void changecolor()
    {
        switch (Form1.worth)
        {
            case 1:
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red); 
                break;

            case 2:
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Orange); 
                break;

            case 3:
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow); 
                break;

            case 4:
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue); 
                break;

            case 5:
                brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White); 
                break;
            default: brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red); break;
        }
    }



    public Food(Random randomfood)
    {
        changecolor();

        x = randomfood.Next(0, fieldsize_X) * squaresize; 
        y = randomfood.Next(0, fieldsize_Y) * squaresize;

        foodrectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, widht, hight);

    }//creat Food
```

I use a timer, so i need to spawn a food before the time have to start. The timer beginns, when you push the arrow-keys.

```
    public void Foodlocation (Random randomfood)
    {
        changecolor();

        x = randomfood.Next(0, fieldsize_X) * squaresize;// 0 = spawnrange to the next food
        y = randomfood.Next(0, fieldsize_Y) * squaresize;

        foodrectangle.X = x; //X.Max = 47 * 20 = 940
        foodrectangle.Y = y; //Y.Max = 38 * 20 = 760

        foodrectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, widht, hight);//spawn first food

    }

    public void drawFood (Graphics paper)
    { 
        paper.FillRectangle(brush, foodrectangle);

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Instead of a colour, i want a png dependent on the "worth" variable.
If "worth" = 1, so the square have the apple.png or something like that.

Comment: you can easily do this with Graphics.DrawImage and then set the correct location

Comment: Your `changeColor` method is leaking a lot of GDI handles.  Brushes need to be disposed.  At the very least, you should have `brush.Dispose();` at the top of that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
public void drawFood (Graphics paper)
{ 
    // Load a png object from a file.
    Image sourceImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\my.png");

    // Draw a portion of the source image.
    paper.DrawImage(sourceImage, foodrectangle.X, foodrectangle.Y, new Rectangle(0, 0, squaresize, squaresize), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

Comment: Good, though you might want to store that image in memory somewhere rather than loading it from disk each time you want to render something. +1

Comment: Thank you guys :)
But it doesn't work. 
I tried to make a switch (fail).
I tried to make a single one like you (fail).
I tried a change
paper.DrawImage(sourceImage, foodrectangle.X, foodrectangle.Y, new Rectangle(0, 0,           fieldsize_X, fieldsize_Y         ), GraphicsUnit.Pixel); thats worked.
But the change with the fieldsizes instead of squaresize, show me just a part of my png and not on the right position. 
Did you know why?

Comment: The rectangle defines the part of the image, that is drawn. if it's not the complete png, then the png is bigger than your squaresize (or fieldsize). The two parameters after sourceImage define the position of your image. You might need to change them, I wasn't completely sure how your corrdinates work.

Comment: Thank you guys :) I got it now!

Comment: Careful with this. You need a `using` around that image loading, otherwise you risk the file being locked the second time you call this.